# assigning a variable to an event in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have an actionscript file in package alpha called beta with a variable INSTANCE that needs a string.  If I import and declare it in my MXML as alpha.beta.INSTANCE = "String" it will run and connect to the instance String. I want to tie this to another input in the MXML such as a user input in a TextArea with id of Foo but I get the error 1120 Access of Undefined property Foo.  I know this is something simple I am messing up, but I thought I would ask the collective genius since I haven't been able to find the right answer after 2 days. Posting the different ways I have tried without success.

```
import alpha.beta;   
 alpha.beta.INSTANCE = "String" //connects to the instance as String

alpha.beta.INSTANCE = Foo.text  //Error 1120 Access of Undefined Property Foo

alpha.beta.INSTANCE = "{Foo.text}" //connects to a an instance with the name of literally {Foo.text} not the input values.  In the sample below I would want it to connect to the 1 instance


<s:TextArea id="Foo" text="1" />
```

Comment: When do you call `Foo.text`? After `creationComplete`?

Comment: it gives you an error because in this case, the assignment phase happens before the Foo component gets instantiated. read on flex component lifecycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put the code in a function, like the application createComplete handler

```
private function creationCompleteHandler(e:Event):void {
    alpha.beta.INSTANCE = Foo.text;
}
```